# How do I apply a mask to an image in a tf.data pipeline?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My tensorflow input pipeline is reading in images for use in a [demosaicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosaicing) network. Given an image tensor of dimension (H, W, 3), I want to produce a "mosaiced" image of dimension (H, W, 3) with 2/3 of the original information zeroed out. This means that I'd like to apply a mask to the array of image data. For example, a 2x2 image

```
[[ [R_11, G_11, B_11], [R_12, G_12, B_12] ],
 [ [R_21, G_21, B_21], [R_22, G_22, B_22] ]]
```

should become

```
[[ [R_11, 0, 0], [0, G_12, 0] ],
 [ [0, G_21, 0], [0, 0, B_22] ]]
```

via the element-wise mask

```
[[ [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0] ],
 [ [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1] ]].
```

Of course, I'm not just dealing with 2x2 images, but with much larger images. The mask I'd like to apply is just a tiling of the 2x2 mask to meet the dimensions of the image. This is not hard to do in numpy, but when I try to operate on the tensors in my `tf.data` pipeline I get the error:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (args_0:0) to a numpy array.
```

from the following code:

```
def bayerize_3d(t_img):
    """
    Inputs:
        img: tensor of dimension [H, W, 3], where H and W are divisible by 2, color channels are RGB
    Outputs:
        bayer: bayerized version of img, a tensor of dimension [H, W, 3] (1/3 of the former information)
    """    
    np_mask = np.zeros_like(t_img)
    np_mask[0::2, 0::2, 0] = 1
    np_mask[0::2, 1::2, 1] = 1
    np_mask[1::2, 0::2, 1] = 1
    np_mask[1::2, 1::2, 2] = 1
    t_mask = tf.convert_to_tensor(np_mask)

    t_bayer = tf.math.multiply(t_img, t_mask)

    return t_bayer
```

For context, I'm using tensorflow 2, and I call `bayerize_3d` from the following:

```
def decode_img(img):
    """Taken from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images"""
    # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
    img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=3)
    # Use `convert_image_dtype` to convert to floats in the [0,1] range.
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    return img

def load_vimeo_data(data_dir, dir_list, bayer_option='3d'):
    """Loads Vimeo-90K training / test data as tensorflow dataset, returns tuple of x and y datasets
    data_dir - path to vimeo90k training / test dataset directory
    dir_list - path to file containing relative directory paths to use for this dataset
    bayerize - either '3d' or '4d' - should """
    # ugly python 3.5 workaround
    target_dir = str( pathlib.Path(data_dir) / 'sequences' )
    #directories = list(map(lambda x: str(x), target_dir.glob('*/*')))

    directories = []
    with open(dir_list, 'rt') as f:
        for line in f:
            directories.append(str(pathlib.Path(target_dir) / line.strip()))

    im1str = tf.constant('/im1.png')
    im2str = tf.constant('/im2.png')
    im3str = tf.constant('/im3.png')

    bayerize = None
    if bayer_option == '3d':
        bayerize = bayerize_3d
    elif bayer_option == '4d':
        bayerize = bayerize_4d

    def process_dir(dir_path):
        im1 = decode_img(tf.io.read_file(tf.strings.join([dir_path, im1str])))
        im2 = decode_img(tf.io.read_file(tf.strings.join([dir_path, im2str])))
        im3 = decode_img(tf.io.read_file(tf.strings.join([dir_path, im3str])))
        return im1, im2, im3

    def bayerize_stack(im1, im2, im3):
        b_im1 = bayerize(im1)
        b_im2 = bayerize(im2)
        b_im3 = bayerize(im3)
        return tf.stack([b_im1, b_im2, b_im3], axis=0)

    def extract_middle(im1, im2, im3):
        im2 = tf.stack([im2], axis=0)
        return im2

    def process_stack(im1, im2, im3):
        return bayerize_stack(im1, im2, im3), extract_middle(im1, im2, im3)

    dirs = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(directories)
    dirs_dataset = dirs.map(process_dir)
    # dataset is bayerized stack "labeled" with true middle frame
    dataset = dirs_dataset.map(process_stack)
    return dataset
```

Surely there is an appropriate way to do this?

Comment: I don't run into any errors running your code in a tf.data pipeline with my own images. Can you show your tf.data pipeline?

Comment: @DMolony I edited my post to include the entire pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to come from trying to create the numpy array from the tensor.

My suggestion is to explicitly pass the image shape into your dataset pipeline and generate the numpy array with these known dimensions.

Alternatively you can set the shape of your input tensor e.g.

```
h = 500
w = 500
t_img.set_shape(h, w, 3)
np_mask = np.zeros(t_img.shape)
```

Comment: Thank you! Explicitly passing the height and width to generate a numpy array with np.zeros worked. t_img.set_shape(...) did not.